# iTunes Sharing Over Wireless Network

Tags: wireless-networking, itunes

I have two PCs (one desktop and one laptop) that connect to the internet through a shared wireless router. Both machines are running Windows 7, and can connect without issue to the net.

I want to share my iTunes library from the desktop to the laptop. I have gone into iTunes on the desktop and checked on share my library, I have also checked look for libraries on the laptop. Both are using the latest iTunes version (9).

I cannot see the iTunes share on my laptop.

I have gone through everything I can think of. I have even enabled telnet client on the laptop and was able to get to port 3689 on the desktop. I can see the desktop in my network through windows as well.

Is there something else I can check out to see why I cannot connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the solution was to replace the Wireless adapter on my Win7 x64 machine. Now everything works great.

Thank you to all who read/responded!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to allow communication through your firewall.

Add iTunes as an allowed program.

Comment: Done. When installed on Win7 - this exception is made. This appears to be set the same way on both machines.

Comment: Can you see network shares between the machines?  Do they show up in the network neighborhood?

Answer (score 0):

okay, as far as I know iTunes runs through bonjour, so first thing to do is to run IM client for instance Pidgin and make sure nothing blocks bonjour, if you get this to work your iTunes library will appear on another iTunes.

Comment: What would an IM client tell me? What should I look for?

Comment: as long as you get bonjour to work thats when your iTunes should work